# Programmatically install facebook.apk before installing MyFbApp.apk

Tags: android, facebook

I am working on an fb application that requires the facebook application to be installed, so what I am trying is that when the user installs my app the facebook.apk should be installed first.. is there a way to accomplish this???

Answer (score 0):

You can check if facebook app is installed this way

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean appInstalled = false;
    try
    {
           pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
           appInstalled = true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
           appInstalled = false;
    }
```

The Facebook app uri is in my opinion `com.facebook.katana`, but you can check that via adb
Then you can eventually start Intent heading to Fecebook page on Google Play..
Hope this helps